# Binary code in 8 bits

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I'm doing a code that converts decimals to binary. I just want my binary number to be in 8 bits. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

long decimalToBinary(long n);

int main() {
    long decimal;

    printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &decimal);
    printf("Binary number = ") << decimalToBinary(decimal);

    return 0;
}
long decimalToBinary(long n) {
    int remainder;
    long binary = 0, i = 1;

    while (n != 0) {
        remainder = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        binary = binary + (remainder*i);
        i = i * 10;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with your code here? What should it be doing (example of input and expected output)?. What is it *actually* doing? (same kind of example). Your format string for reading a `signed long` is wrong; it should be `%ld`, but more importantly should be `std::cin >> decimal;` once you include the proper headers.  And that followup `printf` you're trying to treat like a `std::cout` makes no sense at all.

Comment: @WhozCraig it's the old left-shifting printf

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @M.M Yeah, I know, the only reason it actually compiles. At a minimum the compiler should be warning about an unused expression result.

Answer (score -1):

```
long decimalToBinary(long n) {
    return n & 0xFF;
}
```

or `(n & 0xFF00) >> 8` or `(n & 0xFF0000) >> 16` or `(n & 0xFF000000) >> 24`.  Depends on which 8 bits you want.